# D-link dwm-157 not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, mount, usb-modem, d-link

Community.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on Lenovo G50-70 Laptop. 
I just bought an USB mobile internet dongle D-Link dwm-157. My issue is same as [3G D-Link DWM-157 Modem Install on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426540/3g-d-link-dwm-157-modem-install-on-ubuntu-12-04). I can't make it work.

Basically, I work as a technical support and a client had that issue, that I couldn't solve. So I decided to install Ubuntu and test a solution to his problem.

First I removed the PIN code from the SIM card.
Then I plugged the dongle and a green light lid.
Then in Terminal I execute "**ls /dev/sr***" and I've got output as follows "**/dev/sr0**". It's highlighted in yellow, if that make a difference.
Then I try to mount it with "**sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt**", the output is "**mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0**". When I run "**eject /dev/sr0**", the CD/DVD ROM opens.
When i try "**sudo mount /dev/sr1 /mnt**" the output is "**mount: special device /dev/sr1/ does not exist**". I tried the dongle in all the different USB ports, doesn't work eighter. 
When I execute "**sudo -fdisk -l; mount; lsb_release -a; uname -a**" this is what I see

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

from your question i think /dev/sr0 is your DVD rom so try mounting sr1

`mount /dev/sr1 /mnt` it may be your modems storage.if it's mounted copy the tar.gz file to home directory. if it fails connect it to a windows system, copy the tar.gz to your home directory. after copying the file follow the instruction from this [link](http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/usb/DWM-157/Description/D-Link%20DWM-157%20Linux%20guide.pdf) starting from number 2 ( skip this command `sudo cp xxx.gz /home` it's for copying the installer file to home directory)